# Calculate Throughput

Tags: java, performance

I have a the following scenarios. I am trying to calculate throughput of the java's XSLT transformer. I have 10 threrads, each iterates 1000 times. The task of the thread is to read the XML and XSLT file and trasnform it and write to a new file.

I want to calculate the TPS. Can you please suggest the way to calculate TPS?

Thanks and Regards,

Srinivas.

Comment: I expected something about TPS reports. I am sadly disappointed.

Comment: I fail to see what you are trying to calculate. The throughput will be  very dependent on your input file (size), the complexity of your transformation (stylesheet) and the size of the produced output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you want to start a timer at the beginning and stop it when all threads complete.  That gives you elapsed time = end time - begin time.  Transactions = 10 threads * 1000 iterations = 10000.  TPS = 10000 / elapsed time.

The easiest way to do this kind of timing is with a CyclicBarrier.  Here's a good writeup of using a barrier action with a CyclicBarrier as a timer (see last example):

- http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/11/11/thread-coord/

My final caveat would be that benchmarking something like this is fraught with peril.  Some suggestions:

- Run more than 1000 iterations.  You need to let hotspot warm up.  Preferably you should let the test run at least 10 minutes.
- Don't discount GC times.  You need to be aware of what GC you're using and how its pause times are affecting your results.  Running with -verbose:gc at least a few times is extremely valuable.  See here for more: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/GCPortal/
- Run multiple repetitions in the same process until you see repeatable results.
- Do many runs until you believe the numbers are consistent.